# Is it possible to use a lamp server for serving files from a nas?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, freenas

In my current home-network setup, i am running freenas 8 on a mini-itx box (on which i store all my files). I'm thinking about building an extra l.a.m.p. server with some spare parts (for use in my web-development, and related projects).

I'm thinking it would be great to have this lamp server also be the middle man in serving files (from my nas) to selected friends and family (preferably over a web interface, something like ajaxplorer for example). So in this setup the lamp server will be the gateway between my home-network and the web (and will thus hopefully make it easier to control access from and to the web).

Is this possible? Does anyone have any experience with this kind of setup, and what are the potential pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible.  You could also share them over the web directly via the NAS.  To do it from the LAMP system, you just need to mount the filesystems on the LAMP machine (likely via NFS) and configure your webserver (ftp, ajaxplorer, etc) to use those mounted directories to serve files.  This would basically be the same approach as if you wanted to serve files directly from the LAMP machine.

This is a fairly common approach, and for a home setup there aren't really any caveats, it should just work.

Comment: I also would recommend to have a look at sshfs, espacially for a job like this, since it is extremely to set up.